# Connectedness, continuous functions, and the intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity, connectedness

I want to prove that  for a continuous function mapping a connected space to ℝ such that f(p) never equals s, it follows that f(p) < s for all p or f(p) > s for all s.

So here's what I know so far:

-Because f is continuous and the metric space M is connected, f(M) is connected.

-f(M) is connected in the real numbers, so if $ x,y \epsilon f(M) $ and x < z < y, then $ z \epsilon f(M) $

-I have a feeling the intermediate value theorem will play a part in this, but I'm not sure how.

I'm having trouble relating these three points.

Comment: This is somewaht unclear; are you trying to prove that for a continuous function mapping a connected space to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(p)$ never equals $s$, it follows that $f(p)<s$ for all $p$ or $f(p)>s$ for all $s$?

Comment: Sorry. Yes that is exactly it

Comment: I changed it above:-)

Answer (score 3):

*Proof 1:* If $f(p)\neq s$ for any $p\in M$, then 
$$
    f^{-1}((s,\infty)) \cup f^{-1}((-\infty,s)) = M
$$
The two sets on the left are open and disjoint.  Since $M$ is connected, one of them is $M$ and one of them is $\varnothing$.  So either
$$
    f^{-1}((s,\infty)) = M \implies \forall p \in M,\ f(p) > s
$$
or
$$
    f^{-1}((-\infty,s)) = M \implies \forall p \in M,\ f(p) < s
$$
Q.E.D.

*Proof 2:*
Suppose it is not true that
$$
(\forall p\in M,\ f(p) > s)\text{ or }(\forall q\in M,\ f(q) < s)
$$
Since $s$ is not a value of $f$, we have
$$
(\exists p \in M,\ f(p) < s)\text{ and }(\exists q \in M,\ f(q) > s)
$$
By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $r \in M$ with $f(r) = s$.
This contradicts the condition that $s$ is not a value of $f$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Did you mean p in M? So I can see how to use the intermediate value theorem here, but how does connectedness relate?

Comment: Yes, p is in M. Sorry, on a tablet where typing is slow. I'll edit. The next steps wouldn't need the IVT.  (You could use IVT for a different proof.)

Comment: thanks a lot matthew! I'm still not seeing how to do this without using IVT, what does the hint you gave tell us?

Comment: @user1961722: I fleshed out both proofs.